# google sheets match function - does not match

Tags: google-sheets, match

In google sheets, I use the match function to find a value A in array Y.  The value A appears in array Y.  The match function does not see A in Y.  I have had this happen often.  I try changing the type (eg. multiplying both values of A by 1).  Rarely does anything work.  Sometimes if I copy and then paste over as value it will work.

Example:  Find A in array (A,B,C,D).  The match function seemingly randomly sometimes returns 'no match'

I searched google forums and found an unanswered post from 2010:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2367

Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I can't link to the sheet itself because it's a company sheet.  When I have time later, I will recreate it.  I believe the problem is a type issue of some sort.  I have match(A1,B1:B10,0).  A1 = 47902 and B3 = 47902.  I've tried multiplying both by 1, changing to the same type (eg. plain text, number, etc).  I've had this happen many times over the years in cases just as simple as the one I gave here.

Comment: Great point.  I think changing it to format:number would take care of that, but to be sure, I 'trimmed' with trim() - no luck.  But the funniest thing is that it's been an hour and I looked back and three of the values (3/86) have now matched (nor is it that the sheet has been recalcing all this time).  My guess is that this is one of the many bugs google hasn't taken care of on its 'sheets'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the problem lies with Google sheets.  There's a date type difference between my search item and the key array.  So the solution should be just to make them the same type (eg. plain text).  Sometimes this works immediately, sometimes it works the next day and sometimes it never works.  I've done this on identical sheet copies with those varying results.  Long-short: buggy.  That's the case with a lot of the referencing in google sheets (eg. importrange, etc.).  But overall still a good product and I use it as my primary spreadsheet platform due mainly to the sharing ability.

If anyone from google would like to add to the conversation it would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that MATCH is assuming your array is sorted.  I ran into this problem myself and when I specified the third argument as 0 it worked, but when I didn't MATCH returned the last element of the same data type.  For example, for array N {"---",3,5,2,"---"), MATCH(MAX(N),N) returns 4 but MATCH(MAX(N),N,0) returns 3.

Edit: For clarity, argument 3 is a boolean which should be true if the array is sorted, and defaults to true.